# javascript not loading in HTML file - nodejs + http

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, server

Disclaimer: I am new to node.js so I assume there is a very basic answer to this question.

I am using **node.js** on **Windows**, with **http** module to generate a static page with content generate from a js file.

**Server file (server.js):**

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        response.write(html);
        response.end();
    }).listen(8080);
});
```

**HTML file (index.html):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<div id="div1">
  <p id="p1">This is a static paragraph.</p>
</div>

<p>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="start.js"></script>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**JS file (start.js)**

```
var para = document.createElement("p");
var node = document.createTextNode("This text is loaded from a js file.");
para.appendChild(node);
var element = document.getElementById("div1");
element.appendChild(para);
```

When I load **index.html** directly, I get the following output:

> This is a static paragraph.
>
> This text is loaded from a js file.

^^ this is my desired output.

**Problem:** However, when I use **node.js** and run **server.js**, the **start.js** content does not load. I get:

> This is a static paragraph.

Any help would be appreciated.

FYI, my folder structure

```
/
- node_modules
-- http
-- fs
- index.html
- server.js
- start.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic for appending child nodes seems okay.

I think you should try changing your `src="start.js"` to `src="./start.js"` or `src="/start.js"` just to make sure that you're referencing the path properly. Add a `console.log()` statement in your `start.js` to make sure that it is being loaded.

EDIT: Make sure you are hosting your file on your server. You could add something like `express` or `connect` to help.

To use connect, run `npm install --save connect` in your project directory.

```
var connect = require('connect'),
directory = '/path/to/Folder'; // probably just '/' for all your files

connect()
  .use(connect.static(directory))
  .listen(80);

console.log('Listening on port 80.');
```

[Refer to their docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect) for full instructions and more examples using `http`.

Comment: I tried those alternatives and the path is properly referenced, however the file is not loading since `console.log()` doesn't make any logs. I believe the issue is related to what @BharathRao mentioned i.e. "file is not on the server"

Comment: Yes, that must the issue then. I edited my post with another method you could try.

Comment: I tried your solution with express following instructions on https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html i.e. putting `start.js` in a `/public` folder and it worked! Thank you.

Comment: Glad you got it working! `express` is usually my go-to as well ;)

Answer (score 2):

Every request url that you get for a file needs to be handled by the node server. I would suggest using Express.js as this would ease in handling the different url paths and files can be served directly. But in case you want a pure node.js based implementation, check below code.

To serve a file from the server you will have to modify your server.js to something like this:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    if(request.url=='/'){
        fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {
             if (err) {
                  res.send(500,{error: err});
             }
             response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
             response.write(html);
             response.end();
        });
    } else if(request.url=='/start.js'){
        fs.readFile('./start.js', function (err, jsFile) {
             if (err) {
                  res.send(500,{error: err});
             }
             response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/javascript"});
             response.write(jsFile);
             response.end();
        });
    }

}).listen(8080);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I tried this, and the page is now endlessly loading. I suspect this is due to the fact the server cannot find `/start.js`. I am going to investigate a bit further.

Comment: @Wronski try debugging to find what is the url you get while doing a fetch for start.js, I might have missed something. Feel free to suggest an edit if you get it.

Comment: your code was correct. I had another .js file that was causing the endless loading. Once I removed reference to that file, the code loaded showing: `This is a static paragraph.

This text is loaded from a js file.`

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not able to find the js, Before you reference the js, ensure it is on the server and you can load it from the server, like this: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/start.js'. All of our static files, such as img, css, js should be put on server, only then it will be referrenced.

Comment: I suspect the file is not "on the server" because when I load http://localhost:8080/start.js I get the following error `start.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token` in the chrome console. How do I add a file to the server?

Comment: If start.js is throwing an error at line 1 then it is on the server, you just have a syntax error at line 1. What is your line 1 of that file? Double and triple check it for possible errors.

Answer (score 0):

You app not seeing your javascript file.
Best solution is to use express.

1. create public folder(if you don't have it).
2. Put your javascript file into public folder.

   Import express.

   set static folder.
3. In your .html file write path to .js file like you are in public folder, ex: "/public-subfolder-if-is/yourFile.js"

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
```